# Why does my program keep printing garbage values?

Tags: c

For some reason when i input my time , description and index and click quit to print the array that i have populated with values and strings, i get  a bunch of garbage values printed instead of what i inputed, not sure what im doing wrong. any advice?

For some reason when i input my time , description and index and click quit to print the array that i have populated with values and strings, i get  a bunch of garbage values printed instead of what i inputed, not sure what im doing wrong. any advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 5

struct event    //data type called event which holds time and description for events
{
    int hour; //holds the hour digit between 0-23
    int minute; //holds the minute digit between 0-59
    char description[41];
//holds the description for the reason of the alarm
};

typedef struct event Event; //allows coder to only have to use "Event" instead of "struct event"

int InputRange(int min, int max);
Event* InputEvent(Event *newEvent);
int AddEventAtIndex(Event list[], Event e, int i);
//int InsertionSortEvent(Event list[], int *p_size, Event e);
//void DisplayEvent(Event e);
//void DisplayEventList(Event list[], int size);
//int DeleteEvent(Event list[], int i, int *p_size);

int main (void)
{
    Event EventList[MAX];
    Event e;
    int i=0;
    int eventListSize = 0;
    int choice;

    do
    {

        printf("__= Scheduler v1.0 =__\n");
        printf("1. Schedule an event.\n");
        printf("2. Delete an event.\n");
        printf("3. Display schedule.\n");
        printf("4. Save schedule.\n");
        printf("5. Load schedule.\n");
        printf("6. Exit\n");

        switch(choice = InputRange(1, 6))
        {

            case 1: InputEvent( EventList );
                i = AddEventAtIndex(EventList, e, i);
                break;
        /*  case 2: pHead = deleteStudent(pHead);
                break;
            case 3: printf("Press 1 to search by ID or 2 to search by name: \n");
                scanf("%d", &search);
                if (search == 1){
                    searchStudentID(pHead);
                }
                else if (search == 2){
                    searchStudentlName(pHead);
                }
                else{
                    printf("Invalid selection");
                }
                break;
            case 4: displayStudentInfo(pHead);
                break;
            case 5: saveStudentInfo(pHead);
                break;
            case 6: end(pHead);
                break;*/
        default: printf("Exiting Program\n\n");
        }
    }
    while ( choice != 6 );

    printf("Index #[]\tTime\tDescription");

    for ( int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("\n[%d]\n\t%d:%d \t %s", j, EventList[j].hour,
               EventList[j].minute, EventList[j].description);
    }
}

int InputRange(int min, int max)
{
    int timenumber;

    printf("Please enter a number between %d - %d\n", min, max);
    scanf("%d", &timenumber);
    printf("\n");

    if (timenumber < min || timenumber > max)
    {
        printf("Invalid Entry\n");
        InputRange(min, max);
    }
    return timenumber;
}

Event* InputEvent(Event *newEvent)
{
    if (newEvent != NULL) // quality assurance:
        // make sure the pointer is valid
        {
            printf("Enter the event time:\n");
            newEvent->hour = InputRange(0, 23);
            newEvent->minute = InputRange(0, 59);
            printf("Enter the event description:\n");
            fgetc(stdin);
            fgets(newEvent->description, 41, stdin);
            printf("\n");
        }
        return newEvent;
}

int AddEventAtIndex(Event list[], Event e, int i)
{
    --i;

    printf("Where in the array would you like to store this event\n");
    i = InputRange(1, 5);
    list[i].hour = e.hour;
    list[i].minute = e.minute;
    strcpy(list[i].description, e.description);

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Provided code does not compile. Start by formatting the code with proper indents, fixing compile errors, and then recompiling with the maximum warning level and correcting warnings produced by the compiler.

Comment: You have several problems in your program, see my answer listing them more a proposal to solve them and an example of execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does my program keep printing garbage values?

You use non initialized data, in *main* you have :

> ```
>   Event e;
>   ...
>   i = AddEventAtIndex(EventList, e, i);
> ```

where *e* is not initialized but used in *AddEventAtIndex* :

> ```
> int AddEventAtIndex(Event list[], Event e, int i)
> {
>   ...
>   list[i].hour = e.hour;
>   list[i].minute = e.minute;
>   strcpy(list[i].description, e.description);
> ```

the behavior of *strcpy* with an non initialized value is undefined and can have a dramatic consequences.

Probably the call `InputEvent( EventList );` must be replaced by `InputEvent(&e);`

In

> ```
> for ( int j = 1 ; j < 6 ; j++)
> {
>   printf("\n[%d]\n\t%d:%d \t %s", j, EventList[j].hour, 
>          EventList[j].minute, EventList[j].description);
> }
> ```

You access out of *EventList* when j is 5 and 6, do for instance :

```
 for ( int j = 0 ; j < MAX ; j++)
 {
   printf("[%d]\t%d:%d \t %s\n", j+1, EventList[j].hour, 
          EventList[j].minute, EventList[j].description);
 }
```

But you also write entries never set printing 'garbage values', more the fact to print a string non initialized has undefined effect. A way to separate entries set and not set is to initialize all the hours by 24 and to test that value in the loop to write or not the entry.

I also changed the format because the newline after the index is not compatible with `printf("Index #[]\tTime\tDescription");` and it is better to put the other newline *after* all rather than *before* to flush the output line, so also change `printf("Index #[]\tTime\tDescription");` by `puts("Index #[]\tTime\tDescription");`

*MAX* is not a very good name because it is more a SUP, or just rename it by SIZE

In *main* you do not use *eventListSize*

---

In *AddEventAtIndex*

`--i` must be done *after* `i = InputRange(1, 5);` or just do `i = InputRange(1, 5) - 1;` else when *i* values 5 `list[i]` is out of *list* so you write out of *list* with an undefined behavior.

So finally the parameter *i* is useless, remove it.

The return index is also not used in *main*, you use it to assign *i* and do not used the value of *i* after. *AddEventAtIndex* do not need to return a value.

---

In *InputRange*

You do not check the result of *scanf* so the value of *timenumber* is undefined if a non valid integer was enter and if you do not purge the input so all the next *scanf* to get a number will not success

Also if the value is not in the range you just call `InputRange(min, max);` without returning its value so you finally return the invalid value, put all in a `for(;;)` for instance to only return when the value is correct.

You use *fgets* in *InputEvent*, to mix it with *scanf* to read number is a source of problem, replace the *scanf* by the use of *fgets* then a *sscanf* on the read line

---

In *InputEvent*

When you do `fgetc(stdin);` you probably hope to bypass a newline but if the user enter characters after the number in *InputRange* (supposing a number was enter) *fgets* will read the first of them and *fgets* will not get the expected description. The solution is to do *fgets* then *sscanf* in *InputRange* as I said above allowing you to remove that *fgetc*

---

A proposal taking into account my remarks :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 5

struct event    //data type called event which holds time and description for events
{
  int hour;   //holds the hour digit between 0-23
  int minute; //holds the minute digit between 0-59
  char description[41];  //holds the description for the reason of the alarm
};

typedef struct event Event; //allows coder to only have to use "Event" instead of "struct event"

int InputRange(int min, int max);
Event* InputEvent(Event *newEvent);
void AddEventAtIndex(Event list[], Event e);
//int InsertionSortEvent(Event list[], int *p_size, Event e);
//void DisplayEvent(Event e);
//void DisplayEventList(Event list[], int size);
//int DeleteEvent(Event list[], int i, int *p_size);

int main (void)
{
  Event EventList[MAX];
  Event e;
  int choice;

  /* mark uset entries */
  for (int i = 0; i != MAX; ++i)
    EventList[i].hour = 24;

  do
  {
    printf("__= Scheduler v1.0 =__\n");
    printf("1. Schedule an event.\n");
    printf("2. Delete an event.\n");
    printf("3. Display schedule.\n");
    printf("4. Save schedule.\n");
    printf("5. Load schedule.\n");
    printf("6. Exit\n");

    switch(choice = InputRange(1, 6))
    {
      case 1: 
        InputEvent( &e );
        AddEventAtIndex(EventList, e);
        break;
      /*case 2: pHead = deleteStudent(pHead); 
                    break;
        case 3: printf("Press 1 to search by ID or 2 to search by name: \n");
                    scanf("%d", &search);
                    if (search == 1){
                        searchStudentID(pHead); 
                    }
                    else if (search == 2){
                        searchStudentlName(pHead);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Invalid selection");
                    }
                    break;
        case 4: displayStudentInfo(pHead);
                    break;
        case 5: saveStudentInfo(pHead);
                    break;
        case 6: end(pHead);
                    break;*/
      default: printf("Exiting Program\n\n");
    }
  }
  while ( choice != 6 );

  puts("Index #[]\tTime\tDescription");

  for ( int j = 0 ; j < MAX ; j++)
  {
    if (EventList[j].hour != 24)
      printf("\t[%d]\t%d:%d \t %s\n", j+1, EventList[j].hour, 
             EventList[j].minute, EventList[j].description);
  }
}

int InputRange(int min, int max)
{
  char line[32];
  int timenumber;

  for (;;) {
    printf("Please enter a number between %d - %d\n", min, max);
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL)
      /* EOF */
      exit(-1);
    if ((sscanf(line, "%d", &timenumber) == 1) &&
        (timenumber >= min) &&
        (timenumber <= max))
      return timenumber;

    printf("Invalid Entry\n");
  }
}

Event* InputEvent(Event *newEvent)
{   
  if (newEvent != NULL)   // quality assurance:
    // make sure the pointer is valid
  {
    printf("Enter the event time:\n");
    newEvent->hour = InputRange(0, 23);
    newEvent->minute = InputRange(0, 59);
    printf("Enter the event description:\n");
    fgets(newEvent->description, sizeof(newEvent->description), stdin);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return newEvent;
}

void AddEventAtIndex(Event list[], Event e)
{
  printf("Where in the array would you like to store this event\n");

  int i = InputRange(1, 5) - 1;

  list[i].hour = e.hour;
  list[i].minute = e.minute;
  strcpy(list[i].description, e.description);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
__= Scheduler v1.0 =__
1. Schedule an event.
2. Delete an event.
3. Display schedule.
4. Save schedule.
5. Load schedule.
6. Exit
Please enter a number between 1 - 6
1
Enter the event time:
Please enter a number between 0 - 23
2
Please enter a number between 0 - 59
22
Enter the event description:
descr1

Where in the array would you like to store this event
Please enter a number between 1 - 5
1
__= Scheduler v1.0 =__
1. Schedule an event.
2. Delete an event.
3. Display schedule.
4. Save schedule.
5. Load schedule.
6. Exit
Please enter a number between 1 - 6
1
Enter the event time:
Please enter a number between 0 - 23
3
Please enter a number between 0 - 59
33
Enter the event description:
descr2

Where in the array would you like to store this event
Please enter a number between 1 - 5
4
__= Scheduler v1.0 =__
1. Schedule an event.
2. Delete an event.
3. Display schedule.
4. Save schedule.
5. Load schedule.
6. Exit
Please enter a number between 1 - 6
12
Invalid Entry
Please enter a number between 1 - 6
6
Exiting Program

Index #[]   Time    Description
    [1] 2:22     descr1

    [4] 3:33     descr2
```

note the empty line in the final print, this is because the newline is part of the description, it must be remove is present in *InputEvent*